# Have military rations ever been supplied to crews in space?

Tags: life-support, astronaut-lifestyle, food

Most space food has been specially designed preserved food to meet concerns specific to space flight.

Has any space program supplied MREs or other rations from their military for astronauts?

Comment: I would suspect never,  because MREs are not designed to be crumb/particle-free.  And that's a critical requirement for zero-g foodstuffs.

Comment: It looks like the cosmonaut survival kits have military food included, but I am unable to confirm with a good reference.

Comment: From what I have seen the Soviet survival kits were based on the military pilots survival kits (made sense, manufacturer Zvezda made kits for both military and space) and the food included was rehydratable  biscuit blocks. Not really MRE as such..